# Maximize: x in Vectors[5, R] is not a valid variable

Tags: mathematical-optimization, warning-messages

I am learning how to do optimization with a variable number of variables in Mathematica. I tried to write one experiment that I need to do but I have failed to get even a stripped-down version working. The code is the following

```
y = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Maximize[{Sum[Indexed[y, i]/Indexed[x, i], {i, 1, 5}], 
    ForAll[i,Indexed[y, i]^(1/4) <= Indexed[x, i] <= Indexed[y, i]^(1/2)]}, 
    x ∈ Vectors[5, Reals]]
```

But it says

```
Maximize::ivar: x ∈ Vectors[5, Reals] is not a valid variable.
```

I have tried to re-write the optimization problems in different ways but nothing helped. Any advice on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are two issues. One, the constraint using [`ForAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ForAll) doesn't work, and two, `Vectors[5, Reals]` is not a region:

```
RegionQ[Vectors[5, Reals]]
```

> False

So, one idea is to use [`VectorLessEqual`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorLessEqual) instead of [`ForAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ForAll), and to use `FullRegion[5]` as the region:

```
Maximize[
    {y . (1/x), VectorLessEqual[{y^(1/4), x}] && VectorLessEqual[{x, y^(1/2)}]}, 
    x ∈ FullRegion[5]
]
```

> {1 + 2 Sqrt[2] + 2^(3/4) + 3^(3/4) + 5^(
> 3/4), {x -> {1, 2^(1/4), 3^(1/4), Sqrt[2], 5^(1/4)}}}

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to write this:

```
y = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
xvec = Array[x, 5];
NMaximize[{Total[y/xvec], Thread[y^(1/4) <= xvec <= y^(1/2)]}, xvec]

{11.1334, {x[1] -> 1., x[2] -> 1.18921, x[3] -> 1.31607, x[4] -> 1.41421, x[5] -> 1.49535}}
```

The elements of xvec are the variables x[1], x[2], etc. The Threading is needed so that all the constraints are stated properly. It also works fine with Maximize instead of NMaximize:

```
Maximize[{Total[y/xvec], Thread[y^(1/4) <= xvec <= y^(1/2)]}, xvec]

{1 + 2 Sqrt[2] + 2^(3/4) + 3^(3/4) + 5^(3/4), 
 {x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 2^(1/4), x[3] -> 3^(1/4), x[4] -> Sqrt[2], x[5] -> 5^(1/4)}}
```